# Difficulty involving Rings and Subrings Proving lub contained in fields?

Tags: real-analysis

Oe of the questions in my textbooks is as follows.

Let $$R= \left\{ \frac{n}{10^{k}}: n \in\Bbb Z, k>0\right\}$$

Consider $S$ a subset of $R$ where $$S=\left\{ \frac{3}{10},\frac{33}{100},\frac{333}{1000},\dots\right\}$$

I am asked to show that this set has an upper bound in $R$. 
Then prove whether or not it has a least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$ as well as if it has a least upper bound in $R$.

How does one prove something such as this?
I am familiar with calculus and the reals but im having a hard time translating that knowledge into this weird realms of fields. if there some explanation that could help me borrow from that intuition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: It’s pretty easy to see that $s<1$ for each $s\in S$, since the numerator is always less than the denominator, so $1=\frac{10}{10^1}$ is an upper bound for $S$ in $R$. For the rest, try writing the members of $S$ as decimals: $S=\{0.3,0.33,0.333,\dots\}$. To what rational number is the sequence

$$\langle 0.3,0.33,0.333,0.3333,\dots\rangle$$

converging? Once you know what number it is, showing that it’s the least upper bound of $S$ isn’t very hard, but we can come back to that if necessary.

Finally, you have to decide whether that number can be written in the form $\dfrac{n}{10^k}$, where $n$ is an integer and $k>0$. Again, that’s not too hard once you know what the number is.

Comment: well its obviously 1/3 the problem is you need n and k to be infinitely big to get to 1/3